# Update by partial "_id" in elasticsearch by asterisk

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update a few values of a specific entry of an Elasticsearch Index. I can see the data in the terminal by

```sh
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/pelias/_doc/custompoi:restaurant:33316604?pretty"
```

which returning

```json
{
  "_index" : "pelias",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "custompoi:restaurant:33316604",
...
  "_source":{
    "source": "custompoi"
    "layer": "restaurant"
...
```

where the last portion of `_id`'s `33316604` is unique for each record.
Now I am using the following command and trying to update that record

```sh
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/pelias/_update/custompoi:restaurant:33316604?refresh=true&pretty=true" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.layer = \u0027fast_food\u0027"
}
'
```

The problem is, I have only this part `33316604` of `_id` to search. In a relational DB I can search something like this using `*33316604`. I tried something like that but here the asterisk `*33316604` is not working.

Is there any way I can update the data using only the `33316604` portion of `_id`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure the `_id` field mapping, as mentioned in the [elasticsearch official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html#mapping-id-field).

But there is one way, you can update your data based on the `_id` field.

Create a new index having a `id` field, with an n-gram tokenizer. Use the index mapping as shown below

```
PUT old-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reindex the data from the old index into a new index

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old-index-name"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new-index-name"
  }
}
```

Copy the data of `_id` field into `id` field

```
POST /new-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": "ctx._source.id = ctx._id"
}
```

And then, you can update the data, based on id field

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": "33316604"
    }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.layer = \u0027fast_food\u0027"
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea I think. But I am a little bit confused about `re-index` part. What is the index value of source and destination? How can I get it?

Comment: @Devil'sDream these are not any values, those were my index names. I hv updated the reindex API part. You just need to add your index name, in the `source` and `destination` part

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add that numeric value or entire string as another field ( not _id field)  in the document and use it for search.  `_id` field is a bit [special](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-id-field.html#mapping-id-field); not all queries are supported there.